# How to change the rolling appender time interval in log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am looking to change my rolling appender from every day to every 5 minutes. I want to change it to a lower number in order for me to test that it is working. Any help would be appreciated

**Code:**

```
# RollingFileAppender will print logs in file which can be rotated based on time or size
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName= C://Users/Kai/dev/Cal-2/app_logs/IT/IT_log.txt
appender.rolling.filePattern= C://Users/kai/dev/Cal-2/app_logs/IT/IT_log_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.zip
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}.-%t-%x-%-5p-%-10c:%m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

 

# Rotate log file each day and keep 14 days worth

appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath = C://Users/Kai/dev/Cal-2/app_logs/IT/
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 1
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified

 

# Delete files older than 14 days

appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 14d
```

Comment: I think you should change the `filePattern` to achieve this, but not sure you can set it to 5 mins...

Answer (score 1):

As Usagi mentioned in the comment, you will want to change your `filePattern` to specify minutes (ex. `mm-hh-dd-MM-yyyy`). Then you should be able to use a `CronTriggeringPolicy` with a schedule of `0 */5 * ? * *`.

If you scroll down [this page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.5/manual/appenders.html) pretty far you'll eventually get to the documentation on the `CronTriggeringPolicy`.